# Why can't I use an element of array to call its method?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] array = new Object[1];
        Piece piece = new Piece();
        array[0] = piece;
        array[0].move();
    }
}

class Piece{
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Line 6 doesn't not work and I am not sure why. Shouldn't ***array[0]*** give me ***piece*** and ***piece.move()*** call the method in the class?

Comment: try this ((Piece) array[0]).move();

Comment: The type of the variable `array[0]` is `Object` regardless of what value you put into it.

Comment: When you store a `Piece` as `Object` the compiler does not know anymore that it is a `Piece`.  You have to explicitly tell it. Alternatively use  `Piece[] array`.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description

Answer (score 1):

You are casting Piece as Object when you add it to the Object array.

Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Piece[] array = new Piece[1];
        Piece piece = new Piece();
        array[0] = piece;
        array[0].move();
    }
}

class Piece{
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to make an 8x8 chessboard array that contained different types objects in its index like pawn or rook. How would I do that?

Comment: @Tony You create a class or interface `ChessPiece`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because on line `array[0] = piece;` you are assigning `Piece` object to `Object` which is valid because `Object` is the parent class of all.

But when you do `array[0].move();` you are trying to call the `move()` method from reference of `Object` class.
This is not possible because `move()` method is not declared in `Object` class.

Thus you need to cast like below:

`((Piece)array[0]).move();`

Answer (score 1):

When you store a `Piece` as `Object` the compiler does not know anymore that it is a `Piece`.  You have to explicitly tell it (cast it `((Piece)array[0]).move();`).
Alternatively store objects in `Piece[] array`.

I assume the real motivation is storing different pieces types. In this case they all have to have the same base type. This can be achieved by having all pieces types extend the same base class, or implement a common interface:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movable[] array = new Movable[2];
        APiece aPiece = new APiece();
        BPiece bPiece = new BPiece();
        array[0] = aPiece;
        array[0].move();
        array[1] = bPiece;
        array[1].move();
    }
}

interface Movable {
    void move();
}

class APiece implements Movable{
    @Override
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("APiece moved ");
    }
}

class BPiece implements Movable{
    @Override
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("BPiece moved ");
    }
}
```